# Add/Use geolocation search function in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, address, search, geotag

I am a beginner of QGIS.

I am mapping several specific sites across the Netherlands, with polygons.
In order to "locate" them to begin with, I am using Google Earth to mark them. There I can search the address easily. Then I add this data to QGIS, which obviously doesn't make a lot of sense. The reason I am doing so is, that while I have a Google Maps layer in QGIS, I can't search it, its just working as an "image".

How could I search directly in QGIS on my Google Maps layer for my location in order then to create my custom polygons there directly?

I also see there is OSM as well. But equally I can't search for addresses on there, I reckon it searches for my own geodata then (i.e. strings).

Comment: Nominatim Locator Filter https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nominatim_locator_filter/

Answer (score 5):

QGIS has a built in functionality, it's the [QGIS locator bar](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#locator-bar), it let you search an address using the nominatim geocoder. It wont be as efficient as a search in google map (no autocompletion or trying to guess the location if you made a typo) but it should work.

To use it simply type an address then click on the magnifying glass icon and select nominatim geocoder. If you plan to mostly use the locator bar for geocoding you may go to Setting>Option them select the Locator tab where you could set the Nominatim geocoder as default and/or deactivate other search type.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If one has access to [the Google Maps Platform](https://mapsplatform.google.com/), please proceed with the following workflow:

1. Install the ["Google Maps Geocoder"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/google_maps_geocoder/#plugin-details) plugin
2. Proceed with `Settings > Options... > Google Maps`, where insert the **API key** and choose the Preferred region e.g. Netherlands.
3. Search in the bottom left corner the [Locator bar](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#locator-bar) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). Then by using the `$`-symbol, type desired location and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to that location, like this:

   [image: searching]

If there is not access to the Google Maps Platform, one can try the Nominatim locator filter with a daily limit of 86400 requests. Use the `>`-symbol for searching in the Locator bar. See [the Changelog for QGIS 3.20](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-nominatim-geocoder-integration) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For many countries there are plugins that help you do that.

For the Netherland I found this one:
https://amsterdam.github.io/projects/qgis-pdok-geocoder/ haven't tried it myself but looks alright.

EDIT: And here is the official QGIS plugin address: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pdokbaggeocoder